# Sencha CMD 6.5 does not create 'bootstrap.js'

Tags: extjs, command, ubuntu-16.04, bootstrapping, sencha-cmd

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and running this command below, inside ExtJS SDK folder;

```
root@nuri:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ext-6.5.0# sencha generate app MyApp ../demoapp
```

Sencha CMD runs and finishes without any problem and it keep displays only one line message:

```
[INF] Copying framework to /opt/lampp/htdocs/demoapp/ext
```

It creates the folder "**demoapp**" named as in command but **bootstrap.js** is missing! Thus I can not run the demo app with browser.

All I've noticed; I can not run the `sencha` command in terminal without **root**. It keep says `sencha command not found`. Therefore I'm switching to root with `su` command and then I'm being able to run `sencha` command.

**UPDATE**:

- I've tried this command from Sencha CMD [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.5.0/guides/extjs/cmd_app.html) but still it doesn't create bootstrap.js

`sencha -sdk /path/to/ext6 generate app MyApp /path/to/my-app`

- As well tried thorugh another Folder, inside **/Home** but still same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and the solution:

- I've ran `sencha app build` command in terminal, inside the **demoapp**
  folder and then `sencha app watch`.
- CMD created requried json files as well **bootstrap.js** and now I can display it.

**Conclusion**: Do not wait for `build` and `watch` command to run application on browser! Just do it after generation step...